# How do you handle duplicates in binary tree?

Tags: java, binary-tree

This is the testing part of it, I keep getting a return of 2 instead of fff. 
    I need to have implemented on the bottom to return the duplicates. ?Handling duplicates but not trying to prevent them from inserting it, just have to return correct value.

```
        System.out.println("\nInsering duplicate key: ...");
        tree.insert(2, "fff");
        testFind(tree.find(2), 2, "fff");
```

I need to handle duplicates and return "fff" above ^ is the test code bottom needs to be further implemented.

```
    public V find(K key) {
        Node node = findHelper(key, root);
        if (node == null) {
            return null;
        } else {
            return (V) node.entry.value;
        }
    }


    public Node findHelper(K key, Node node) {
        if (node.entry.key.compareTo(key) == 0) {
            return node;
        }
        else if (node.entry.key.compareTo(key) > 0) {
            if (node.leftChild == null) {
                return null;
            } else {
                return findHelper(key, node.leftChild);
            }
        } else if (node.entry.key.compareTo(key) < 0) {
            if (node.rightChild == null) {
                return null;
            } else {
                return findHelper(key, node.rightChild);
            }
        }
        return node;
    }
```

Comment: If you do have duplicates, are you intending to return *all* duplicates back?

Answer (score 1):

If a node entry key equals to query, you should continue searching in child nodes too:

```
public List<Node> findHelper(K key, Node node) {

    int c = node.entry.key.compareTo(key);

    if (c == 0) {
         List<Node> result = new ArrayList<>();
         result.add(node);
         result.addAll(findHelper(key, node.leftChild));
         result.addAll(findHelper(key, node.rightChild));
         return result;        

    } else if (c > 0) {
        if (node.leftChild == null) 
            return Collections.emptyList();
        else 
            return findHelper(key, node.leftChild);

    } else {
        if (node.rightChild == null) 
            return Collections.emptyList();
        else 
            return findHelper(key, node.rightChild);
    }
}
```